# In which cases should `==` be used over `localeCompare` and viceversa, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

What are the pros and cons of each of them when compared to each other?
In which cases should `==` be used over `localeCompare` and viceversa, in Javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: http://conceptf1.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/javascript-triple-equals-vs-double-equals-operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localeCompare` is not the same as `==`. When you compare two variables using `==`, you check whether or not the variables have the same content. This will return a boolean (true/false). However, `localeCompare` does not return a boolean but an int instead.

You will receive a `0` when the two variables are the same, but you will however receive either `1` or `-1` if your variables are not the same. The value is based on whether the first variable comes before or after the second variable in sort order.

So I myself would use `==` when I'm purely validating if two variables are the same, but `localeCompare` can become handy when you want to see what variable comes first in sort order, however it *can* be used to compare two variables to see if they are the same.

```
string a = "hello";
string b = "world";

a == b // returns false
a.localeCompare(b); // returns -1
```

To answer your question slightly, these are the characteristics / pro's and cons of using either of the examples given:

**Using `==`**

- Returns a boolean instead of a string/integer/...
- Easier to read by most people

**Using `localeCompare`**

- Returns an integer (-1, 0 or +1)
- Can be used to sort variables

Answer (score 3):

They are not at all the same!

Non-strict comparison compares strings to see if they are the same (only included strings as that's what `localeCompare` works on, types are irrelevant).

```
"test" == "test" // true
```

`localCompare` is a lot more than that, it returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order, and in the specified language.

```
'a'.localeCompare('c') // returns a negative value, i.e. -1 etc, a comes before c
'a'.localeCompare('a') // returns 0, they are the same
'c'.localeCompare('a') // returns a positinve value, i.e. 1 etc, c comes after a
```

note that the sort order used is entirely implementation dependent, but in most browsers it will be alphabetical

or language specific

```
'ä'.localeCompare('z', 'sv')); // a positive value: in Swedish, ä sorts after z
```

As it return a negative integer, zero or a positive integer, it's useful in functions such as `sort()` which expects the return of the sorting callback to be just that, a negative integer, zero or a positive integer.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Your second example will return `-1` instead of `-2` ;-)

Comment: @KevinVoorn - that's browser dependant, but as my Chrome also returns `-1` I'll change it

Answer (score 2):

`localeCompare` doesn't just check for equality in value. It also compares the values when they're different, and returns a `1 / -1` depending on which value is higher. It's return value is in no way similar to a equality check.

`localeCompare` can be used for sorting strings, as the return value is different from `==` when the 2 values aren't the same, `==` can *only* be used for determining equality (in value, not type).

For example:

```
"2".localeCompare(2) // 0
"2".localeCompare(1) // 1
"2".localeCompare(3) // -1

"2" == 2 // true
"2" == 1 // false
"2" == 3 // false

"b".localeCompare("b") // 0
"b".localeCompare("a") // 1
"b".localeCompare("c") // -1

"b" == "b" // true
"b" == "a" // false
"b" == "c" // false
```

The return value from `localeCompare` happens to be exactly what `Array.prototype.sort()` expects to be returned from it's handler.

Answer (score 1):

`localeCompare` is very useful to implement a sorting (ascending or descending) function:

```
myLabelsArray.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
});
```

Indeed, `localeCompare` returns `-1`, `0` (if equals) or `1` (based on locale language rules), allowing to get a sorting.

It would take more lines to implement it with `==` + `<`, explicitly returning integers.